# Translation of Jordan and Wigner's original paper?

Tags: hilbert-space, fermions, second-quantization, specific-reference, pauli-exclusion-principle

Has the original paper on the Jordan and Wigner transformation ever been translated to English?

Jordan, P., Wigner, E. *Über das Paulische Äquivalenzverbot.* Z. Physik 47, 631–651 (1928). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01331938 https://inspirehep.net/literature/1486

Comment: I don't think it has been ever translated. Since Wigner died in 1995, the copyright the journal holds will expire only in 2065; earlier than that any translation could only be legally published with permission by Springer Nature (good luck with that).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the translation in a book. Duck I, Pauli W, Sudarshan E C G. Pauli and the spin-statistics theorem[M]. World Scientific, 1997. Have fun reading it!

Comment: Truly appreciate for taking the time for this. Thanks